# Comandos para fazer upload de arquivos para o github

Tags: upload, github, cloud

Estou tentando fazer upload de arquivos no GitHub. Já criei o diretório e no GitHub criei a conta.

Não consigo estabelecer uma conexão com o GitHub quando entro na pasta onde contém o arquivo que quero hospedar e digito esses códigos abaixo:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m 'Teste de github'
git remote add origin git@github.com:usuario/repositoriogithub.git
git push origin master
```

Os dois últimos comandos dão erro pois não conseguem estabelecer uma conexão com o servidor.

Possivelmente deve ser por causa da chave ssh que eu nao configurei na instalação porque eu nem sei onde fica essa *keys*. Meu sistema operacional é Windows XP SP3, vocês sabem onde fica essa chave ssh e como configurar no site e no Windows?

Obs: Já tenho o repositório criado, mas não consigo enviar para o GitHub meus arquivos.

Comment: Pergunta boba, mas você trocou `usuario` pelo seu usuário e `repositoriogithub.git` pelo seu repositório? .__.

Comment: boba né rsrs, ja fiz isso e nao funciona.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada aqui: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#platform-windows

`Tip: If you have GitHub for Windows installed, you can use it to clone repositories and not deal with SSH keys. It also comes with the Git Bash tool, which is the preferred way of running git commands on Windows.`

Comment: nao consegui nem com eles me ajudando.         o erro quando eu digito esse comando: git remote add origin git@github.com:ktinho456/server.git é fatal: remoter origin already exitis.     e quando eu digito esse codigo git push origin master; da o seguite erro; fatall remote error: ktinho456/:ktinho456/server.git is no a valid repositori

Comment: Já tentou clonar seu repositório, colocar os arquivos que você precisa lá e então *commitar* e fazer *push*?

Comment: ja mas nao funfa nao consegi pelo fileilla mas nao tem como dar start no arquivo que quero exemplo pasta/a/srver.js quando tento da erro de url esse openshift eta me dando uma surra.

Answer (score 6):

Se o repositório já existe é mais fácil usar o `git clone`

```
git clone git@github.com:usuario/repositoriogithub.git
```

Pronto. Faça as alterações necessárias. Para subir os arquivos você precisa fazer o seguinte:

```
git add *
git commit -m 'Sua mensagem de commit'
git push -u origin master
```

Pronto.

Comment: É muito importante explicar mais o git add. Antes do commit nos precisamos usar o git add para incluir determinados arquivos no índice. Após isso usamos o commit e o push.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck verdade =), não tinha conhecimento dessa informação. Obrigado pela contribuição.

Comment: Estou fazendo pelo terminal no ubuntu, só que sempre aparece isso (aparece depois que eu digito (git push -u origin master): 

! [rejected] master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/usuario/repo.git'
dica: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
dica: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
dica: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
dica: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
dica: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Você sabe o que é? Eu acho que deve ser uma coisa muito boba, mas não to entendendo.

Comment: @MarcielliOliveira De acordo com o que você postou você está tentando subir uma versão desatualizada dos seus fontes. Você precisa dar um `git pull` antes de dar um `git commit` e `git push -u origin master`. Pode ser que você tenha que resolver conflitos. Quando tudo estiver resolvido você pode subir os fontes normalmente.

Comment: @MarcielliOliveira Editei a resposta. Veja se te ajuda.